# How can I drive this LCD TFT with an Arduino?

Tags: spi, lcd

As I understand it, the Arduino comes with a TFT library which uses SPI to drive LCD TFTs. I recently bought a TFT labelled "HY-32.TFT" on the front and "HY-TFT320_262k heyaodz111211" on the back.

It uses an XPT2046 touch screen controller, but I'm more interested in just getting something on the screen currently.

To use the Arduino library, I need to connect pins:

- SCLK
- MOSI
- CS
- DC
- RESET

But I can't see these apart from some similarly named ones associated with TP (touchpad?) and SD (sd card), as the photo shows:

[image: back]
[image: front]

Is it possible to drive this with my Arduino? If so, how?

UPDATE: It looks like the datasheet for the controller and the board can be downloaded from [3.0" 3" TFT LCD Module Display + Touch Panel + PCB adapter](http://www.icstation.com/module-display-touch-panel-adapter-p-2292.html).

Comment: http://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/3.2TFT_LCD

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm seeing, the touch screen and card reader use SPI but the LCD uses a bunch of Digital I/O lines. The link in Gerben's comment includes a library for the LCD that might be what you're looking for. I hope you're using a ATMega board as it doesn't look like an Uno or similar board will have enough I/O for the LCD.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for "arduino lcd tft shield" on ebay you should if a few shields for your kind of lcd. But all of them require an Arduino MEGA (or DUE). 
You could also use some kind of a shift register to drive this lcd with an Arduino UNO (or other small boards).